# Installed Xubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, Sound Problem, try everything on the internet

Tags: 14.04, sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

## Hi, I'm noob like super Noob

but i wouldn't ask without trying anything out there first
and i have tried

the **sudo alsa-force-reload**
Not working

I have tried changing the default output as well, not working

My laptop has no sound.

Install and purge and reinstall Alsamixer
did that, not working

Also i still have pulseaudio in my laptop.
Install and purge and reinstall,
Not working

Below is my Alsa Info,
Appreciate any helps as i tried to fix this since last night :)

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=86d6d5436d6bb54063a70b4b0f606eca63c1e94b

THx